# ignition timing light trigger current

Tags: power-supply, circuit-design, inductance, induction

I've built an ignition timing light, following: 
http://citroen.tramontana.co.hu/en/ignition/stroboscopic-timing-light

here the original schematic:

[image: schematic diagram]

I've changed some components:

1. Instead of the [BD135](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/cd00001225.pdf) BJT, I've used a [BD128D](http://www.elenota.pl/datasheet-pdf/158259/Telefunken-Electronic/BD128?sid=e207cb22f4340a8ef2dd4b20c639e395).
2. Instead of R3 (4M) I've used a 3.9M R
3. as LED1 I've used a  [Nichia NFSL757GT LED](https://www.nichia.co.jp/specification/products/led_spec/NFSL757GT-E(3538D)R70%20R8000%20R9050.pdf)
4. as setting current R5, i've used two 220ohm R in parallel
5. Instead of a 240ohm R (R1) I've used a 220ohm R

Here the schematic as modified:

[image: modified schematic]

When I apply it to the spark plug HT lead, the LED flickers as it has to do, but it is barely switched on.

The trigger cable is connected to the spark plug lead insulation via a crocodile clip and it collects the signal via capacitive coupling with the cable.

- The cable insulation is made of PVC (dielectric constant 3.19) and is 3mm thick.
- The inner cable is made of copper 1mm thick.
- The voltage provided by the ignition coil is 14 000 V.
- There is about 1000 spark each minute.
- The crocodile clip is 5mm wide.

The trigger cable is an audio cable, which I believe is shielded. I've connected the shielding to the battery - pole)

I think that maybe the trigger signal collected is not enough to open the thyristor and the transistor.

Is it possible to calculate the capacitive coupling?

I would like to try to simulate the trigger signal with a Keithley power supply. Which current and voltage do I have to set, in order not to destroy nothing?

Comment: 1)Did you notice the part that says, "Using a shielded cable for the trigger input line is essential to avoid false input from the other cylinders."? If you haven't done that, you'll be switching on the LED when _any_ cylinder fires, which means the supply capacitor won't charge very well. 2) What LED (exactly) are you using? 3) Just how bright is "barely switched on"? This sort of strobe won't be very bright due to the short drive pulses, so you need to take that into account.

Comment: What LED did you use? Link please.

Comment: Closing as unclear until you show the schematic of *exactly what you built*.  No, I'm not going to keep scanning back and forth between the schematic and your text description of what the part values really are.

Comment: updated,I've put both the schematic, hope now is more clear!

Comment: That circuit doesn't make much sense for direct connection to the spark plug lead.  Is TRIG really coming from a magnetic pickup, perhaps?  What exactly is TRIG connected to?

Comment: According to what written at the original link, the trigger has to be connected to the spark plug lead insulation through an alligator clip. I think that the trigger is collecting the signal through capacitive coupling with the spark plug lead

Comment: _”I think that”_ Please don’t. Simulate, calculate and measure.

Comment: This is what I would like to confirm or reject, but I'm not able to calculate this, can you help to make this?

Comment: What's C1 doing with a 220nF value? That will kill any output form your trigger pickoff. Maybe the original circuit meant 220pF?

Comment: this could be! It's not specified in the original, I've supposed it was nF. I can change to 220 pF and try if it doesn't damage the circuit!

Comment: More to the point, R1 being only a few hundred ohms is going to completely kill the signal. If you're going to have a resistor there at all, it needs to be 100x to 1000x the value. Try 100k or so.

Comment: Ok, can I change both the C1 capacitor from 220nF to 220pF and the R1 from 220ohm to 150k?

Comment: Please consider that that part of the circuit is needed for protection, since the trigger signal can be not constant, as @Neil_UK suggested.

Comment: By  the way, can anyone explain simply how that rc circuit with the diode is supposed to protect from the spikes coming from the ignition coil sparks?

Comment: I've added a new question for this, for sake of clarity.
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/398021/questions-on-snubber-circuit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used such a circuit for my ostroboshcope. For picking up the signal you will have to use a pick up coil. As it is not to be found ready made you will have to make your own. First lets make a bobbin for pick up coil. Take a piece of cardboard about one inch in width and wrap it very loosely around the ignition cable and paste the end of the cardboard strip to the wrapped cardboard with glue. Now the cylindrical bobbin is ready and wind about 100 turns around this bobbin using 34SWG enamelled copper wire. Solder leads of the coil to a screen wire and connects these leads to your in put directly. When you want to check an ignition wire, remove the spark plug top 
, insert the ignition wire through the bobbin of the pick up coil and fix the spark plug top. Thats all . And change the resistor at input to 1000 ohms.